# Проиграть jpg картинки как видео

Tags: html, flask, jpeg

Есть серия картинок в jpg формате. Как можно проиграть на странице html как видео не конвертируя в видео формат а за счет быстрой смены во Flask

Answer (score 2):

По моему опыту с разными браузерами, наиболее приемлемый вариант для достижения плавности смены JPEG-картинок — это замена background-image блока + использование progressive JPEG (Полезно, например, когда нужно плавно подставить фото в более высоком разрешении).

Для анимации кадров можно попробовать CSS-анимацию. Конечно, если подгрузить их заранее.

```css
.frame {
  --p1: url(https://cdn2.chikiriki.club/img/tmp/1.jpg);
  --p2: url(https://cdn2.chikiriki.club/img/tmp/2.jpg);
  --p3: url(https://cdn2.chikiriki.club/img/tmp/3.jpg);
  --p4: url(https://cdn2.chikiriki.club/img/tmp/4.jpg);
  --p5: url(https://cdn2.chikiriki.club/img/tmp/5.jpg);
  --p6: url(https://cdn2.chikiriki.club/img/tmp/6.jpg);
  width: 560px;
  height: 410px;
  background-color: #756a41;
  background-image: var(--p1), var(--p2), var(--p3), var(--p4), var(--p5), var(--p6);
  background-size: cover;
  animation: sequence 800ms 100ms infinite; 
}

@keyframes sequence {
  0%    { background-image: var(--p1), var(--p2), var(--p3), var(--p4), var(--p5), var(--p6) }
  16.7% { background-image: var(--p2) }
  33.4% { background-image: var(--p3) }
  50%   { background-image: var(--p4) }
  66.7% { background-image: var(--p5) }
  100%  { background-image: var(--p6) }
}
```

```html
<div class="frame"></div>
```

Comment: Прикольный финт вместо предзагрузки поставить все фоны одновременно. Если картинки закешированы, то и с одним фоном для каждого значения анимации нормально работает.

Answer (score 1):

Делал подобное, сразу скажу, что это не решение, кадры в любом случае будут дергаться, вообще рекомендую, не обновлять изображения каждый раз. А сделать серию элементов `canvas` заранее загрузить на них изображения, и потом быстро менять их через javascript.

**Но лучше чем костыль, эту идею в принципе, не назвать, имхо**

Answer (score 0):

В тег img нужно написать такой источник, который бы формировал multipart/x-mixed поток следующего формата

```
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary="MyMotionJPEG12345"

--MyMotionJPEG12345
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<jpeg bytes>
--MOBOTIX_Fast_Serverpush
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<jpeg bytes>
--MyMotionJPEG12345
... and so on ...
--MyMotionJPEG12345--
```

Между кадрами делаете задержку на стороне сервера. Это хорошо работает если картинки берутся не из файлов.

Другой вариант это сжать жепеги в "гифку" формата webm

```
fmpeg -framerate 1 -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" \
    -c:v libvpx  -crf 12 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.webm
```

чтоб не потерять цвета можно `-pix_fmt yuv444p`, crf качество от 0 лучшее до 50 худшее

Answer (score 0):

Сначала скачиваем все картинки, чтобы они были в кэше, а потом по таймеру меняем `src` у тега `img`. За счёт того, что картинки уже находятся в кэше, будут помменяться мнговенно. Впрочем, так скорее слайдшоу сделать можно, чем видео, а для слайдшоу предварительное выкачивание картинок не требуется.

Comment: Скорее всего даже с кэшем будет мерцать, особенно если картинки большие

Comment: @andreymal, ну от желаемого fps зависит, но вроде не должно. Ну и я на соседнем ответе попробовал сейчас один фон оставить - работает норм.

Answer (score 0):

написал следующее решение.
через переменную z передаем список с путями до jpg файлов

```
{% block img %}
    <img name="slideshow">
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
<script>
var i = 0;
var images = {{ z|safe }};
var time = 35;

function slideShow() {
    document.slideshow.src = images[i]
        if (i < images.length - 1) {
            i++;
            } else {
                i=0;
            }
    setTimeout("slideShow()", time);
}

window.onload = slideShow;
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Переводите в формат gif
2. Скачиваете себе программу для создания gif-анимации
3. Делаете у себя локально такая картинку
4. Загружаете на свой сайт

Comment: gif это 30 мегабайт минута с 256 цветами - прошлый век...

Comment: @eri, можно 256 цветов на каждый кадр, так что цвета формально не ограничены. Впрочем, за счёт размера файла. Ну и постараться надо. А вообще, webp.